# The difference between absurd reasoning and contraposal reasoning

Tags: formal-languages, automata

What is the difference between absurd reasoning and contraposal reasoning?
To show that a language is not regular

Comment: What's the context in which you encountered these terms?  Can you tell us more?

Comment: I saw in different exercises, to shiw that a language is not regular we can use absurd reasoning or contraposal reasoning...

Comment: Ex for L=anbn.... People use absurd or contraposal... I want to know the difference with this two cases.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard those terms in the context of computer science.  When you mention "contraposal reasoning", I've never heard that term before, but I suspect that might be a reference to proving the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).  When you mention "absurd reasoning", I've never heard anyone use that specific phrase, but I suspect you might be referring to [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction), also known as [reductio ab absurdum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum), which is Latin for reduction to absurdity.

These are general proof techniques. They're not specific to showing that a language is not regular.

---

General advice: I recommend that you try to avoid proof by contradiction.  It's a valid proof technique, but my experience is that it often leads beginners awry and causes them to make mistakes in the proof.  I recommend instead proving the contrapositive; it leads to more straightforward proofs where it is easier to avoid errors, and spot where you went wrong if you do make an error.

Comment: RAA in the form of "if $P$ holds then we can derive a contradiction, therefore $\not P$ holds" is fine. That's how you prove a negative statement like "$L$ is not a regular language". This case, however, is almost always conflated with "if $\not P$ holds then we can derive a contradiction, therefore $P$ holds", which is what "proof by contradiction" often refers to and I agree *this* form of reasoning should be avoided,. This applies to proofs that use $(\neg P\to\neg Q)\to(Q\to P)$ too (but not the converse). Many CS results are amenable to constructive proofs which are clearer.